# drone.io: containerd: write /proc/14/oom_score_adj: permission denied

Tags: drone.io

I am trying to reverse engineer the **drone.io** `docker` plugin and understand how to run the docker daemon in a pipeline step (DinD).

**drone.io** uses the library `github.com/cncd/pipeline` to compile and execute .drone.yml files.

The first thing the `plugins/docker` does is to start the docker daemon:

```
+ /usr/local/bin/dockerd -g /var/lib/docker
```

This works if fine in the official plugin, but I cannot get it to work with my own image where I do the same:

**pipeline.yml**

```
workspace:
  base: /go
  path: src/github.com/fnbk/hello

pipeline:
  test:
    image: fnbk/drone-daemon
```

**fnbk/drone-daemon/run.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/local/bin/dockerd     # <= ERROR: containerd: write /proc/17/oom_score_adj: permission denied

# ...
```

It will give me the following error:

```
containerd: write /proc/14/oom_score_adj: permission denied
```

The full example can be found on github: https://github.com/cncd/pipeline/pull/45

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your plugin to a whitelist via the `DRONE_ESCALATE` environment variable, which is passed to the server. This is the default value:

```
DRONE_ESCALATE=plugins/docker,plugins/gcr,plugins/ecr
```

So you would pass something like this:

```
-DRONE_ESCALATE=plugins/docker,plugins/gcr,plugins/ecr
+DRONE_ESCALATE=plugins/docker,plugins/gcr,plugins/ecr,fnbk/my-custom-plugin
```

Note that this should be the image name only. It **must not** include the tag.

Comment: It works! Thank you for pointing me in the right direction :-)